# Build multiple where clauses with linq

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I'm writing a dotnet core MVC web app with EntityFrameWorkCore and Sqlite.

I'm trying to build a dynamic where clause based on data provided by the query string, there could be multiple key value pairs passed in the query string and I want to add them all to the where clause, I thought I could do it like this but it returns me all rows from the initial query.

```
public class Application
{
    public Application()
    {
        Data = new List<Data>();
    }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    [Required][Display(Name = "Application Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid PublicKey { get; set; }
    public Guid PrivateKey { get; set; }
    public bool HideFromSearch { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
        DataItems = new List<DataItem>();
    }
    public int DataId { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    public List<DataItem> DataItems { get; set; }
}

public class DataItem
{
    public int DataItemId { get; set; }
    public int DataId { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Where code

```
var apps = context.Applications.Include(app => app.Data).ThenInclude(data => data.DataItems).Where(app => app.PublicKey == publicKey);

foreach (var item in Request.Query)
{
    apps = apps.Where(q => q.Data.Any(r => r.DataItems.Any(s => s.PropertyName == item.Key && s.PropertyValue == item.Value[0] )));
}
```

Comment: do you get an idea of all the column which will be queried in the request query

Comment: Try LinqKit where you can build dynamic predicates and apply it to where clause. It is open source. Refer this link https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/

Comment: Hard to believe that the added `Where` conditions don't reduce the number of `apps` returned. Do you actually mean that you want to filter the included DataItems?

Comment: Yes, I want to only return the DataItems matched by the subsequent queries.

Comment: That's the ever-recurring filtered `Include` question. It's not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Dynamic Linq in a project and think it is what you are looking for to solve complex dynamic queries.

[Scott Guthrie sample](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

[Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/)